# Move all Python packages to new computer (same versions)

Tags: python

I need to mirror all my Python settings and modules on Computer A vs Computer B.

I could list all packages/modules in computer A using `pip list` and then install them on computer B one by one - but there are literally ~ 100s of packages.

Is there a better/quicker way to achieve this?

In addition:

1) When overwriting previous installations, for example, do I have to use `pip install --force-reinstall "pandas==0.23.0"`?

2) Is there a way to exclude selected packages (some personal, redundant modules)?

Both machines are Windows and run the same Python version.

Comment: just zip the installation and overwrite onto the old one to make an exact copy. There is also the "requirements" option, where you can install a list of packages, not one by one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the old system

```
pip freeze >frozen.txt
```

Then copy the output file to the destination system and

```
pip install -r frozen.txt
```

You can't have both detailed control and quick convenience; if you want more control, manually prune the file before installing the packages.

A common convention is to manually add the packages which your code directly depends on to a file called `requirements.txt`; then just run `pip install -r requirements.txt` on the destination system.

Rather than have an endlessly raging battle between packages with different and possibly conflicting requirements, explore using a virtual environment for each.

Comment: if you have anaconda and pip is not available use conda install -c anaconda pip